# Javascript / Moment - Group array by object values

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by, momentjs

I want to create a 2d array of days and times over a period of 36 hours.

The output I'm trying to get is:

```
Wed 18th
  00:00am
  01:00am
  02:00am
  03:00am
  ...
  22:00pm
  23:00pm
Thur 19th
  00:00am
  01:00am
  02:00am
  03:00am
  ...
```

...til we hit 36 hours. I want to create a `select` with `optgroup` for a form.

Basically the current days time range and the next days time range give or take.

So far I have this:

```
const start = moment().startOf('day');

const times = [];

let hours = 36 * 60;

for (let i = 0; i < hours; i += 1) {
    const value = moment(start).add(60 * i, 'minutes');

    const time = {
        value: value.format('HH:mm A'),
        label: value.format('ddd, Do, HH:mm A'),
        day: value.format('ddd, Do'),
    };

    times.push(time);
}
```

This gives me an array of dates and times.

I've tried to group by the day value to achieve the above output but cant manage to achieve it.

This is what I had so far - its broken though.

```
let daysTimes = [];

times.forEach((time) => {
    daysTimes.push(time.day);
});

daysTimes = _.uniq(daysTimes);

times.forEach((time) => {
    if (daysTimes[time.day] === time.day) {
        daysTimes[time.day].push(time);
    }
});

console.log(daysTimes);
```

My `daysTimes` array just has the two days in it. No times.

I'm using `momentjs` library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using flat array use an object with day as keys and arrays for values. Then iterate that object to built the `<select>`

```js
const start = moment().startOf('day');

const groups = {};// change to object

let hours = 36;

for (let i = 0; i < hours; i += 1) {
  const value = moment(start).add(60 * i, 'minutes');
  // get day for object key
  const day = value.format('MMM D');
  // add day property if it doesn't exist
  groups[day] = groups[day] || [];

  const time = {
    value: value.format('HH:mm A'),
    label: value.format('ddd, Do, HH:mm A'),
    day: value.format('ddd, Do'),
  };
  // push hour object to day array
  groups[day].push(time);
}

Object.entries(groups).forEach(day => {
  const optGroup = document.createElement('optgroup')
  optGroup.label = day[0];
  day[1].forEach(h => {
    optGroup.appendChild(new Option(h.label, h.value))
  })
  document.getElementById('sel').appendChild(optGroup)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel"><option></option></select>
```

Comment: Hi Charlie,  Thanks for adding your input. I think I see where I was failing to create the inner times array correctly. Also, this is a nice little trick - `groups[day] = groups[day] || [];` I didn't actually copy your code snippet 100% - rewrote my own using your approach and its all working as expected now. Thank you!